# PHP DOMDocument::loadHTML() breaks on semicolon in attribute

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse set of html pages from cyrillic site with PHP DOMDocument.

With some pages there are no problems but with some pages that simply doesn't work.

Code I'm using to find out what's wrong:

```
$file = file_get_contents('example.html');
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$head = $xpath->query('//head/*');
foreach ($head as $h){

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($h->nodeName);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

For "good" pages result is:

```
title
meta
link
link
meta
meta
link
link
script
script
```

For "bad" pages:

```
title
meta
```

Html-code of bad pages looks like

```
<title>Разъем;[Red]-9011150</title>
<meta name="description" content="Разъем;[Red]-9011150" />
```

With bad pages I'm also getting warning in error.log

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Couldn't find end of Start Tag meta in Entity
```

When I'm trying to printf(getAttribute('content')) on meta tag, I'm getting only a part of string:

```
Разъем
```

so I assume that semicolon in attribute is a problem here. Or those semicolons could be encoded on "donor" pages with some kind of html-entities.

What can I do with that?

Comment: can you put up `example.html` in your question?, can't reproduce any issues from your posted code: https://3v4l.org/J9pKJ dom warnings are common you can ignore them with flags `LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR` or libxml_use_internal_errors call, but we cant tell if for bad pages its to do with `;` which its most likely not

Comment: The issue happens only when I'm trying to get content of remote page. If I copy source code as html string or as separate html file, there is no issue.

I cannot provide a links due to NDA.